# Handling hundreds of AI efficiently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

To practice AI, I decided to make a AI simulation game like Cuboid Sandbox. Like Cuboid Sandbox, it would have 3 teams of AI (however mine has red, green, and blue rather than red, yellow, and blue).

In Cuboid Sandbox, there was a max of 750 in total and mine has no limit (yet). Through testing, I've found that Cuboid Sandbox doesn't seem to have any drops in framerate no matter how many AI there currently is (using bandicam's framerate counter since there's none in the game so it may be slightly inaccurate although it never looked choppy/laggy).

And in mine, I start to drop to 40fps at around 100 AI in total.

I've tracked this down to where I update my food lists for the AI

Food is separated by each team (if a team has no food left, it goes to the nearest) and for each AI I set a list called 'availableFoodSources' to a list called 'redFood' that's set in the spawner function when it spawns the food on startup and only updates when a food source is destroyed or a new one is spawned.

At large amounts of AI this causes a lot of lag.

There's also another similar loop (removed due to immense amount of lag) where I check for if an enemy tribe distance is less than 20 by loop through all other AI tribes and checking the distance for each one.

I'm not sure how to tackle either of these issues.

Also I'm using StateMachineBehaviour in unity which removes my ability to (easily) use coroutines.

Here's the bit of code where I update availableFoodSources:

```
if (aIController.team == Color.red)
{
    availableFoodSources = spawner.redFood;
}
if (aIController.team == Color.green)
{
    availableFoodSources = spawner.greenFood;
}
if (aIController.team == Color.blue)
{
    availableFoodSources = spawner.blueFood;
}
if (!Attacking)
{
    if (animator.transform.GetComponent<AIController>().hunger > 30)
    {

        GameObject f = FindClosestFoodSource(animator.transform);
        Vector3 closestFoodPos = f.transform.position;

        Debug.DrawLine(animator.transform.position, closestFoodPos);
        closestFoodPos.y = animator.transform.position.y;
        animator.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(closestFoodPos);
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("Walking", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Caching. There's no reason to recalculate those values *every frame.*

Comment: Sounds like you need one of the spatial subdivision data structures for your distance checks.  BSP, KD-Tree, Quadtree, etc.  If you already have colliders on these things, you could try using Physics.OverlapSphere instead of iterating over everything and doing distance checks yourself.